# Liquibase - change on delete type of foreign key for a table

Tags: liquibase

Is it possible to change the foreign key on delete method from `NO ACTION` to `SET NULL` in liquibase?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. There's `onDelete` attribute in `<addForeignKeyConstraint>` which you can set to:

- CASCADE
- SET NULL
- SET DEFAULT
- RESTRICT
- NO ACTION

If you already have a foreign key, then you can drop existing constraint and recreate it with the settings you need.

```
<changeSet id="changeset-id" author="changeset-author">
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
        <foreignKeyConstraintExists foreignKeyName="fk_foo_bar"/>
    </preConditions>
    <dropForeignKeyConstraint baseTableName="table_foo" constraintName="fk_foo_bar"/>
    <addForeignKeyConstraint baseTableName="table_foo" baseColumnNames="foo_col"
                             constraintName="fk_foo_bar"
                             referencedTableName="table_bar" referencedColumnNames="bar_col"
                             onDelete="SET NULL"/>
</changeSet>
```

Comment: I'm not sure about all databases, but for MySQL the default policy for `ON DELETE` is `NO ACTION`. So in case of MySQL if you haven't previously specified `ON DELETE` policy, everything should be alright and no data will be lost.